# Is it possible to make a progress bar for loading multiple csv files with D3js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, data-visualization

I am following this progress bar animation started by Mike Bostock,

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941

but I want to show the loading progress of multiple files using [Queue.js]

https://github.com/mbostock/queue

Can we add a progress loading bar computed by the number of files loaded divided by the total number of files?
The native "progress" of d3.csv is only for one file loading.

Following is the code to parallel load multiple csv files.

```
 var finalData = {};
 var q = queue(), // create the queue
    dataSources = [ // the data sources
        'myData_key1.csv',
        'myData_key2.csv',
        'myData_key3.csv',
        ...,
        'myData_key30.csv'
    ];

// Go through each data source and add it to the queue:
dataSources.forEach(function (source) {
    q.defer(function (callback) {
        d3.csv(source, callback);
    });
});

// Wait for all requests to be completed:
q.awaitAll(function (error, results) {
    console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: You could try moving the code for updating the progress bar into its own function. Then, for the `progress` event for each file have it update an array that contains the progress of each file and then call the method for updating the progress bar. In that method you could sum the array of progress and divide by the length to get the overall progress %. If you knew the filesize beforehand you could also add weighting to give more accurate loading.

Comment: @JSBob Could you elaborate how to move the code for updating the progress bar into its own function?